flutter_quill package gives me error "Service connection disposed" and crashes the app
I'm using flutter and I want to integrate rich text editor and I came across this package flutter_quill: ^10.8.2
It always gets me an error when I put it in the yaml file:
flutter_quill: ^10.8.2
but when I remove It, the app runs just fine in my emulator.
Here's my error:
Xcode build done.                                           340.0s
Lost connection to device.
getVM: (-32000) Service connection disposed

The app crashes every time I run it.
I appreciate the help in advance.
